# Clarifications on Poisson Regression

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, generalized-linear-model

I am watching this [Bloomberg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrFj0xpGd2Q&list=PLnZuxOufsXnvftwTB1HL6mel1V32w0ThI&index=17) course on machine learning, and i need help on understanding the application of Poisson Regression. So it goes like this

Let $Y=\{1,2,3,...\}$ and let $X$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d.$

We can then model $Pr(Y_i|X_i) = e^{W^TX}.$ The vector $W$ can then be found using an optimization algorithm. But, $e^{W^TX}$ is **not always** an integer. So, my question is how do we predict a particular $Y_i$ given $X_i.$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Poisson regression we use exponential link function. This means that
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y | X] = e^{W^TX}.
$$
Note that the expression above contains the expectation, not a probability. The expression is known as *intensity* and is usually denoted with $\lambda(X)$. Conditional on $X$, variable $Y$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda(X)$. This means that
$$
P(Y = k | X) = \frac{\lambda(X)^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda(X)} = \frac{e^{kW^TX}}{k!} e^{-e^{W^TX}},\ \ \ k = 0, 1, 2, ...
$$
As you can see, $Y$ takes only non-negative integer values.

Comment: I see. This cleared it up. I appreciate your help sir!